# Recent posts with thumbnail, title, date and category - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

in Wordpress, I am trying to display my most recent posts in a list. I have being able to list the links, but cant do the same with post thumbnail, title, date and category. What am I doing wrong?

```
    <?php $recent_posts = get_posts('numberposts=5');
                            if($recent_posts) { ?>
        <ul class="article_list">
            <?php foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ) { ?>
                <li class="regular">
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($recent->ID); ?>">
                        <div class="text">
                            <p class="category"><?php echo the_date();?></p>
                            <h3 class="article_title"><?php echo get_the_title( $post_id ); ?></h3>
                            <p class="date"><?php echo the_date();?></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mask">
                            <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url();?>" alt="" class="art_img">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do it, using `WP_Query`

```
<?php
// args query
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    // display only posts in specifics categories (slug)
    'category_name' => 'cat-a, cat-b'
);

// custom query
$recent_posts = new WP_Query($args);

// check that we have results
if($recent_posts->have_posts()) : ?>

    <ul class="article_list">

        <?php 
        // start loop
        while ($recent_posts->have_posts() ) : $recent_posts->the_post(); ?>

            <li class="regular">
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                    <div class="text">
                        <p class="category"><?php echo the_category(); ?></p>
                        <h3 class="article_title"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h3>
                        <p class="date"><?php echo the_date();?></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mask">
                        <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url();?>" alt="" class="art_img">
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    </ul>

<?php endif;

// reset query
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! How can I have the category displayed?

Comment: @Fernando Souza code updated to display the category

Comment: Thanks again, how can I display multiple categories?Lets say, I want to display a post that is in A and B category at the same time.

Comment: @Fernando Souza  code updated with `'category_name' => 'cat-a, cat-b'` in `args`

Answer (score 1):

Try below code its working for me.

```
       <?php $recent_posts = get_posts('numberposts=5');
                               if($recent_posts) { ?>
            <ul class="article_list">
               <?php foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ) { ?>
                   <li class="regular">
                       <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($recent->ID); ?>">
                           <div class="text">
                                 <p class="category"><?php echo  get_the_category( $recent->ID );?></p>
                                 <h3 class="article_title"><?php echo get_the_title( $recent->ID); ?></h3>
                               <p class="date"><?php echo  get_the_date( $recent->ID );?></p>
                           </div>
                           <div class="mask">
                               <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($recent->ID,'full'); ?>" alt="" class="art_img">
                           </div>
                       </a>
                   </li>
               <?php } ?>
            </ul>
```